# Nock is intercepting my request, but my AJAX request is erroring out

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, nock

I'm testing an AJAX request made using `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
export default function requestToTest() {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'https://example.com/service');

  xhr.onload = () => {
    console.log('onload');
    // etc.
  };

  xhr.onerror = () => {
    console.log('onerror');
    // etc.
  };

  xhr.send();
}
```

So I set up a test using Nock (and Mocha):

```
describe('requestToTest()', () => {
  it('should handle a successful request', () => {
    nock('https://example.com')
      .log(console.log)
      .get('/service')
      .reply(200, { some: 'json' });

    requestToTest();

    expect( /* things I want to check */ ).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

When I run this test, `xhr.onerror()` fires, not `xhr.onload()`. However, from observing Nock's output from the call to [`log()`](https://github.com/node-nock/nock#logging), I know for certain that Nock is intercepting my AJAX request and that the intercepted request matches Nock's expected URL.

Why is `xhr.onerror` being called instead of `xhr.onload` in my test?

Comment: I never did completely figure this out, but I think it's because `XMLHttpRequest` is only defined in a browser environment, not in Node.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, I used the [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch) library. This library is an alternative to `XMLHttpRequest` for making AJAX requests and is expressly designed to work more or less identically in browser environments and in Node.js/test environments.

In general, using a library designed to smooth out the differences between AJAX requests in the browser and making a request from the testing environment seems like the solution to this problem.